# Bar charts in Haskell-d3js

Tags: haskell, d3.js, data-visualization

I decided to poke through the [d3js](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/d3js) library in Haskell but after it didn't install through Stackage.

```
$ stack install d3js

Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.2 from implicit global project's config file: /home/john/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      base: needed (>=4.6 && <4.7), 4.8.2.0 found (latest applicable is 4.6.0.1)
    needed for package d3js-0.1.0.0
```

Instead I got the more interestin idea of looking through the source of [d3js-haskell](https://github.com/nebuta/d3js-haskell).  If I could install the library this could be one of the simplest examples: a bar chart.

```
 import Control.Monad
 import qualified Data.Text as T
 import D3JS

 test :: Int -> IO ()
 test n = T.writeFile "generated.js" $ reify (box "#div1" (300,300) >>= bars n 300 (Data1D [100,20,80,60,120]))
```

Even with this simple example I have a number of questions.  **How does `reify` work ?**  I had to look up the word in a dictionary:

> to regard (something abstract) as a material or concrete thing
>
> #### Did you know?
>
> *Reify* is a word that attempts to provide a bridge between what is abstract and what is real. Fittingly, it derives from a word that is an ancestor to "real" - the Latin noun *res*, meaning "thing." Both "reify" and the related noun "reification" first appeared in English in the mid-19th century, though "reification" is a few years older and some dictionaries consider "reify" to be a back-formation of the noun. In general use, the words refer to the act of considering or presenting an abstract idea in real or material terms, or of judging something by a concrete example.

That having been said the **reify** function in the d3.js library turns Haskell entities representing d3.js objects into actual d3.js code.  Do we have examples of a reifiable object?  We can fine one:

```
reify (box "#div1" (300,300) >>= bars n 300 (Data1D [100,20,80,60,120]))
```

The object in parentheses is a reifiable object.   A tour of the source code is both enlightening and discouraging:

```
-- |Instances of Reifiable can generate a JavaScript code fragment.
class Reifiable a where
    reify :: a -> Text
```

This was taken from [d3js/Type.hs](https://github.com/nebuta/d3js-haskell/blob/master/D3JS/Type.hs) Are there examples of reifiable objects? Let's look at [d3js/reify.hs](https://github.com/nebuta/d3js-haskell/blob/master/D3JS/Reify.hs):

```
instance Reifiable Data1D where
    reify (Data1D ps) = surround $ T.intercalate "," $ map show' ps

instance Reifiable Data2D where
    reify (Data2D ps) = surround $ T.intercalate "," $ map (\(x,y) -> T.concat ["[",show' x,",",show' y,"]"]) ps

instance Reifiable (JSFunc params r) where
    reify (JSFunc name params) = T.concat [name,"(",T.intercalate "," $ map reify params,")"]

instance Reifiable JSParam where
    reify (ParamVar name) = name
    reify (PText t) = T.concat ["\"",t,"\""]
    reify (PDouble d) = show' d
    reify (PInt d) = show' d
    reify (PFunc (FuncTxt t)) = t
    reify (PFunc (FuncExp f)) = T.concat["function(d,i){return ",reify f,";}"]
    reify (PFunc' f) = reify f
    reify (PArray vs) = T.concat ["[",T.intercalate "," $ map reify vs,"]"]
    reify (PChainValue v) = reify v
```

These are examples of reifiable types but these don't tell us **how charts are constructed in haskell-d3js?**

```
-- | box parent (w,h) makes an SVG container in a parent element with dimension w x h.
box :: Selector ->  (Double,Double) -> St (Var' Selection)
box parent (w,h) = do
    assign
        $ ((d3Root
            >>> select parent
            >>> func "append" [PText "svg"]
            >>> width w
            >>> height h
            >>> style "background" "#eef") :: Chain () Selection)

bars :: Int -> Double -> Data1D -> Var' Selection -> St ()
bars n width ps (Var' elem) = do
    let bar_w = width / (fromIntegral n)
    v <- assign $ Val' (mkRectData bar_w ps)
    execute $
        (Val elem :: Chain () Selection)
        >>> addRect v
        >>> fill' "red"
```

These examples supposedly work.  It looks like we are committed to red bars ( I haven't even seen the chart yet).

---

Let me end by some discouraging footnotes in the source code.  This from [chart.hs](https://github.com/nebuta/d3js-haskell/blob/master/D3JS/Chart.hs)

```
-- This modules provides high-level functions for drawing common charts, such as bar charts and scatter plots.
-- Those functions also exemplify how to compose primitive functions to achieve complex drawing.
-- This module will be expanded in the near future.
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what your question is, but here is how to get the d3js demo to run:

1. Run these commands:

   ```
   stack new demo
   cd demo
   cabal get d3js-0.1.0.0
   ```

Make sure the `resolver:` setting in stack.yaml is relatively new (e.g. >= 5.0)

2. In the `stack.yaml` file change the `packages` stanza to read:

   ```
   packages:
   - '.'
   - d3js-0.1.0.0
   ```
3. In the file `d3js-0.1.0.0/d3js.cabal` modify the `build-depends` line to read:

   ```
     build-depends:       base >=4.6
   ```

(i.e. omit the upper bounds on `base`)

4. In `demo.cabal` make the `library` stanza look like:

   ```
   library
     hs-source-dirs:      src
     exposed-modules:     Lib
     build-depends:       base >= 4.8 && < 5, d3js, text
     default-language:    Haskell2010
   ```
5. Use this for `src/Lib.hs`:

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

   module Lib
   where

   import Control.Monad
   import qualified Data.Text as T
   import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
   import D3JS

   someFunc :: IO ()
   someFunc = putStrLn "someFunc"

   test :: Int -> IO ()
   test n = T.writeFile "generated.js" $ reify (box "#div1" (300,300) >>= bars n 300 (Data1D [100,20,80,60,120]))
   ```
6. Run `stack ghci` and run something like `test 13` function. Look at the output in `generated.js`.

The `d3js` package hasn't been updated for a while, and it imposes a too restrictive upper bound on the `base` package. It turns out that it will compile fine with the latest `base` so we're making the d3js source code part of our own project and tweaking it to get it to compile.

Comment: This is great you got it to run.  I wonder what happens when you make charts that aren't among his examples?

Comment: @ErikR might as well consider submitting your patch of build rules into the `d3js` package so people can simply `stack install` without the tweaks.